# Is this UML Use Case too detailed?

Tags: uml, modeling, use-case

Is this use case **diagram** over complicated?  I'm trying to implement a use case for the first time, and I'm trying to get it within the ball park.

[image: Use Case Diagram]

Comment: Your diagram depicts a use case *diagram*, not a use case. A use case corresponds to each ellipse in your diagram.

Comment: @CesarGon, I knew that sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jordan, your use case is missing out the system name at the top.

And there is no over-complicated Use Case Diagram, as long as it fits the requirements of the client.

P.S: By the way, the following Use Case Diagram is one of my assignment in school (so it's not for a system to be built, but similar anyway). It's way complex than what you have there, but it's not over-complicated because the system needs all these use-cases. Imagine drawing the use case of Twitter or Facebook.

> [image: Use Case Diagram]
>      Merlion University Student Association System Use Case Diagram

Comment: I have not forgotten the name, I have omitted it because it is proprietary. Does any think I could combine "Create Budget" and "Modify Budget."  Or do I need to include viewing use cases as well?

Comment: It'll be clear and good to separate use case for different actions. This shows that the user can do different actions to a particular object. documentations and UML have to be clear and precise, to minimize the misunderstanding between clients and project teams. I'd have written all "Create Budget", "Update Budget", "Clear Budget", "View Budget".

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look overly complicated, but you're missing the part that goes on the right, which is the actions in the box use/affect. For example, Add Account may communicate with a database, in which case you'd put a box on the right (outside of the center box) called Database and have Add Account point to it.

Comment: Be careful with this one.  Only show things outside the box if they're really outside the scope of the system you're building.  You may use a db to implement your system - but then it's /part/ of the system, not external to it, and so doesn't belong on diag.

Comment: I don't have a definite method of persistence.  I was going to create several interchangeable persistence modules for flat files, XML, database, etc... None of them are outside the scope of the system though.  This is a single-user stand-alone-application in its first iteration so there really is only one actor. I can foresee multiple roles, but that seems overkill at this point.  My paramount goal with this project is flexibility.  I have implementation all figured out, I just wanted for the first time to properly document the design of my application.